# Gulp get a ls of a directory

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, gulp, ls, dir

I have a directory **assets** with a number of images inside. Inside my JavaScript code, I have an array, with the same list of images, that I use to preload everything. It means I have twice the same information, the list of images, both in my JavaScript and in my filesystem. I would like to have a gulp task to list all those images, and populate the array in JavaScript, with something like:

var listFiles = require("list-files-in-folder");
var images = listFiles("./assets/");

Do you know of any plugin who does that? Or a simple way to implement it maybe?

Comment: This would be a client's JS code querying a folder on a server for files, correct? Or are you asking how a nodejs server can get all the files in a folder?

Comment: No, it would be during the build, so strictly for the dev workflow. When I run gulp, I expect it to find every reference of "require("list-files-in-folder"), understand the associated variable, and then replace every call to it by an array (or even a string, I'm not difficult) of the specified folder.

In the same fashion, I currently use https://github.com/substack/brfs which allows to require the content of a text file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're talking about nodejs, take a look at [this](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob)

```
var glob = require("glob")

// options is optional
glob("**/*.js", options, function (er, files) {
  // files is an array of filenames.
  // If the `nonull` option is set, and nothing
  // was found, then files is ["**/*.js"]
  // er is an error object or null.
})
```

Comment: I'm not speaking about node. Nonetheless the answer is useful as it will help me to find a similar gulp plugin. Thanks

Comment: Actually, I can use it as is, I didn't know you could use node modules in a gulpfile that easily. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JohanLAJILIlajili.com This module is pretty simple, and gulp was built off of node, so it only makes sense. Glad to help :)